# What is the relevance of the constant in the clearance equation?

Tags: pharmacology, human-physiology

I have seen the equation for drug half lives described variously as (0.7xVd)/Cl, (0.693xVd)/Cl, and (ln2xVd)/Cl.

What is the origin of this numerical constant in the numerator? What does it signify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation for drug half life](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53136/derivation-for-drug-half-life)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). At a minimum please search on this site for similar questions that have already been asked such as the one suggested by @rotaredom. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 